# How to change the visibility of CascadingDropDown control

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, cascadingdropdown

What is the preferred method to change the visibility property of a .NET Ajax Control Toolkit `CascadingDropDown` control? I would like to render the control "invisible" when a `null` value is returned from a query.

It appears that "OnSelectedIndexChanged" event does not fire from the `<asp:DropDownList>` when using the toolkit extender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I would just target the `DropDownList` that the `CascadingDropDownExtender` is attached to with the `display:none` css style.  You could do this in javascript on the page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideDDL(){
        // Get the DropDownList by its ID value
        var ddl = document.getElementById("<%= myDropDownList.ClientID %>");
        // If there are no items in the drop down, hide it
        if (ddl.options.length == 0)
            ddl.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

And then, in your `DropDownList` markup, just add the function above to the client-side `onchange` event:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="myDropDownList" onchange="hideDDL();" ... >
    ...
</asp:DropDownList>
```

*Note: Obviously, you will want logic in the javascript function to indicate whether or not the DropDownList should be hidden (such as checking to see if the control has no elements to select, etc).  If you have trouble with that, let me know and I can try and help with that too.*
***EDIT***: I have added a possible example of said logic =)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm a little unclear on the above technique. E.g. if ID="myDropDownParent" OnSelectedChange event is controlling ID="myDropDownChild", would ID="myDropDownParent" contain the onchange property? And the var 
   ddl = document.getElementById("<%= myDropDownListChild.ClientID %>;... in the script?

Comment: BTW, the above did work. Thanks again! Being a javascript noob, how would you check for an empty or null value in the Child element?

Comment: @soulia I've added the check to see if the drop down is empty =)  If this helped you, feel free to upvote or accept this answer (or both!).  Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you. One thing that bothers me in general with this toolkit is that I need to implement a script patch to cover a basic property. The AJAXToolkit tool that I used is a CascadingDropDown "Extender" that happens to obliterate some basic DropDownList properties. "Extender" implies an addition of features, not replacement, or even worse, disable. Other programmers please comment as appropriate.

Comment: @soulia Yes, that's part of why I do not use the AJAX Control Toolkit any more.  It's rather burdensome.  I tend to use jQuery for things like this now; there's a little bit of a learning curve, but it's completely worth it.